# SQL Server: Moved files, can't start, can't configure

Tags: sql-server

I had to move the data files for a SQL Server 2014 database to make some space.

Now the service doesn't want to start any more, saying:

> Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   FCB::Open failed: Could not open file \data\MSSQL12.DBNAME\MSSQL\DATA\MSDBData.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 3 (The system cannot find the path specified.).

Indeed the `<oldPath>` doesn't exist any more. The service doesn't start, so the usual ways of configuring locations don't work.

Is there a way to tell the thing where to look for the files?

Answer (score 0):

The error messages 17204 and 17207 indicate that an error was encountered while SQL Server attempted to open the database files during the startup process.

These error messages contain the following information:
Name of the SQL Server function that is attempting to open the file
The state information distinguishes multiple locations within a function that can generate this error message
The full physical path for the file
The File ID corresponding to the file
The Operating System error code and error description. In some instances only the error code will be provided.

The operating system error information printed in these error messages is the normal cause that results in these error messages. Common causes for these these error messages are a permission problem or a incorrect location or path problem.

i highly Recommend you to bring back The Database Files in The Previous Locations on your Hard Drive and The use common scenario to move databases Mentioned Below:
[Moving User Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345483.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I can't return them though due to disk space restrictions. In addition I presume it'd fail to start too as the location has been changed in too many places (and obviously I'm wondering how come there's more than one, some seemingly inaccessible.)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually start the service from the command line and specify file locations

e.g. -d master_file_path
Is the fully qualified path for the master database file (typically, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL\Data\master.mdf). If you do not provide this option, the existing registry parameters are used.

And then once the service is up and running use the usual ways of configuring locations.

Can't remember if StackOverflow approves of links, but https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190737.aspx is where the details are.

Answer (score 0):

If you needed space, move only the user datafiles. MSDBData.mdf, master.mdf, tempdb.mdf and model.mdf are system databases and they don't take much space. They won't event grow much (except tempdb with can be easily moved using ALTER DATABASE)

To correct the situation, you need to put the files back where they were (yes all of it) then you can detach all databases using

```
exec sp_detach 'user_bd'
```

Since you can't do that, then you should at least restore the 4 system databases (MSDBData.mdf, master.mdf, tempdb.mdf and model.mdf)